# Test Class on @future method won't pass

Tags: future, failing-tests

I'm trying to finish my test class for a @future method, but I just can't seem to figure out my syntax.  We have an automated system that creates User records.  We've added a trigger than uses the User record to create a Contact.  The class works, but I can't get coverage.

Trigger

```
trigger NewUserCreatedTrigger on User (after insert) {
    user[] users = trigger.new;
    NewUserCreatedNotification.sendEmail(users);
    NewUserCreatedNotification.createUserContact(Trigger.newMap.keySet());
}
```

Class

```
public class NewUserCreatedNotification  {

    public static void sendEmail(user[] newUser){
        for (user u : newUser){
            Messaging.SingleEmailMessage mail = new Messaging.SingleEmailMessage();
            String[] toAddresses = new String[] {'SA@company.com'};
            mail.setToAddresses(toAddresses); 
            mail.setSenderDisplayName ('Salesforce Support');
            mail.setSubject('A New Salesforce User has been created in ORG-2'); 
            mail.setPlainTextBody(GetMessageBodyText(u.ID)); 
            Messaging.sendEmail(new Messaging.SingleEMailMessage[]{mail});
        }
    }

    public static string GetMessageBodyText(Id userID){
        user q = [select id, name, firstname, lastname, ProfileID, email,UserRoleID, userrole.name, profile.name, CreatedDate,LastLoginDate,FederationIdentifier from user where id =: userID];
        return ' A new user record for '+ q.name +', has been created in ORG-2.\n Please confirm that this user has the correct security and Role settings.\n\n Name:  '+
                q.name+'\n Email Address:  '+
                q.Email+'\n Profile:  '+
                q.Profile.Name+'\n Role:  '+
                q.UserRole.Name+'\n Federation ID:  '+
                q.FederationIdentifier+'\n Created Date:  '+
                q.CreatedDate;      
    }


@future
public static void createUserContact(set<ID> recordIDs){    
        list<user> users = [Select ID, Firstname, Lastname, title,department,phone, email,street,city,state,postalcode,country from user where id IN :recordIDs];
        for (user u: users){        
            account myFirm = [Select ID from account where name = 'CorpName'];
            Id contactRecordTypeId = Schema.SObjectType.Contact.getRecordTypeInfosByName().get('Employee').getRecordTypeId();
            Contact userContact = new Contact(
                user__c = u.ID,
                ownerID = u.id,
                AccountID = myFirm.id,
                FirstName = u.firstname,
                Lastname = u.lastname,
                RecordtypeID = contactRecordTypeId,
                Title = u.title,
                Department = u.department,
                Phone = u.Phone,
                email = u.email,
                MailingStreet = u.street,
                MailingCity = u.city,
                MailingState = u.state,
                MailingPostalCode = u.postalcode,
                MailingCountry = u.country
                );
            insert userContact;

        }
    }
}
```

Test Class

```
@isTest
private class NewUserCreatedNotificationTestClass {
    static testMethod void GetMessageBodyTextForAGivenUserTest(){

        profile p = [Select ID, Name from Profile where name = 'Admin Assistant'];

        //create account record
        account testAccount = new account(name = 'CorpName',recordtypeid='012o0000000Qw64');
        insert testAccount;

        //create and insert user record
        user testUser = new user(firstname='Testy', lastname='McTesterson', alias='McTest', email='TestyMcTesterson@testcorp.com', username='TestyMcTesterson@testcorp.com',TimeZoneSidKey='America/Chicago', LocaleSidKey='en_US', EmailEncodingKey='ISO-8859-1', ProfileId=p.Id, LanguageLocaleKey='en_US');
        insert testUser;

        String actualValue = NewUserCreatedNotification.GetMessageBodyText(testUser.Id);

        System.assert(actualValue.Contains('A new user record for Testy McTesterson, has been created in ORG-2.'));   
        System.assert(actualValue.Contains('Name:  Testy McTesterson'));
        System.assert(actualValue.Contains('Email Address:  testymctesterson@testcorp.com'));
        System.assert(actualValue.Contains('Profile:  Admin Assistant'));
        System.assert(actualValue.Contains('Role:  null'));
        System.assert(actualValue.Contains('Federation ID:  null'));
        System.assert(actualValue.Contains('Created Date:  '));  

        Test.startTest();        
            Contact[] contacts = [SELECT Id from contact WHERE lastname='McTesterson'];
            System.assertEquals(1, contacts.size());  
        Test.stopTest();


    }
}
```

The class sends an email when a user record is created.  The test class verifies the body of the email.
The class then creates a contact from the user detail.  We want to assert that a record then exists.  This is where it fails.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order for the @future method to be invoked in a test method you need to set the test.startTest() and test.stoptest();

You are getting your records to assert within this block. The @future is not invoked until AFTER test.stopTest();

so change it to:

```
@isTest
private class NewUserCreatedNotificationTestClass {
    static testMethod void GetMessageBodyTextForAGivenUserTest(){

        profile p = [Select ID, Name from Profile where name = 'Admin Assistant'];

        //create account record
        account testAccount = new account(name = 'CorpName',recordtypeid='012o0000000Qw64');
        insert testAccount;

        //create and insert user record
        user testUser = new user(firstname='Testy', lastname='McTesterson', alias='McTest', email='TestyMcTesterson@testcorp.com', username='TestyMcTesterson@testcorp.com',TimeZoneSidKey='America/Chicago', LocaleSidKey='en_US', EmailEncodingKey='ISO-8859-1', ProfileId=p.Id, LanguageLocaleKey='en_US');

        Test.startTest();        
            insert testUser;

        String actualValue = NewUserCreatedNotification.GetMessageBodyText(testUser.Id);

       Test.stopTest();

        System.assert(actualValue.Contains('A new user record for Testy McTesterson, has been created in ORG-2.'));   
        System.assert(actualValue.Contains('Name:  Testy McTesterson'));
        System.assert(actualValue.Contains('Email Address:  testymctesterson@testcorp.com'));
        System.assert(actualValue.Contains('Profile:  Admin Assistant'));
        System.assert(actualValue.Contains('Role:  null'));
        System.assert(actualValue.Contains('Federation ID:  null'));
        System.assert(actualValue.Contains('Created Date:  '));  


            Contact[] contacts = [SELECT Id from contact WHERE lastname='McTesterson'];
            System.assertEquals(1, contacts.size());  



    }
}
```

Comment: I tried that, but I get error:  Class.NewUserCreatedNotificationTestClass.GetMessageBodyTextForAGivenUserTest: line 28, column 1  (which is the system.assert for the contact record count)

Comment: Ignore above.  Typo.  Retesting . ...